# Can this be considered as a programming language?

Tags: python, programming-languages

I've created a Python program which a read from a .TXT file , read it and compile it.
Sample Program:

```
function func1,(x/y),3
print "121",arg..x
print "123"
print "124"
function func2,(x/y),3
print "121"
print "123"
print "124"
function func3,(x/y),5
print arg..y
print "123900",arg..x
print "1245"
newlist [1,2,3,6,8,9,9,9,99,9,9,9,99,9,9,9,999]@save
call func3/(1,"B")
end program
```

Prints

```
B12390011245
```

It has own unique set of rules , it can do loops , function , arrays , objects etc.
I can even write some sorting algorithms in it. It is slow ... Can I call it as a programming language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A programming language is a formal language comprising a set of strings that produce various kinds of machine code output.
> [Wikipedia page of "Programming language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language)

Seems like your project fits with the definition. By extension, note that many things may be considered as a programming language, including the Microsoft Powerpoint macros for example.

If the question is : "Am I able to do anything useful with this language?", the answer will depend on the details of your language, which you didn't give.